# Custom attribute of a XML tag using C# object serialisation

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Can I accomplish something like this with .NET?

Lets suppose I have the following class, whose objects I would like to serizlize using `XmlSerializer` adding the `foo` attribute to the `Name` tag.

```
public class Person {
    [SomeXMLTagAttribute(Name="foo", Value="bar")]
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

And when serialisation takes place I would like the result to be:

```
...
<Person>
  <Name foo="bar">John Doe</Name>
</Persion>
```

`foo` and `bar` are compile time constants.

It is not mandatory to be a C# attribute (`SomeXMLTagAttribute`), but this is a minimal example. In the real case I have a lot of nested classes and I would like a simple way to manage `foo` and `bar`.

I have read the documentation and SO answers, but couldn't find any information about it. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Might be not easy to do with default `XmlSerializer` because it's VERY inflexible. You might have better luck with custom xml serializers if you are fine with using something else than XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Use xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {

           XElement xml = new XElement("People", Person.people.Select(x => new XElement("Name", new object[] { new XAttribute("foo", x.attribute), x.value})));

        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public static List<Person> people = new List<Person>();


        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string attribute { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I am afraid that this solution is not going to scale well with much larger and more complex class than Person.

Comment: I use Xml Linq all the time with large classes when straight serialization will not work.